# Changing default alignment of a dropdown menu list

Tags: html, css

I did a simple CSS-only dropdown menu like the snippet below:

```css
.menu-container {
  width: 60px;
  float: right;
  border: 1px solid #999
}

.menu-container .menu {
  display: none;
  list-style: none;
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 80px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}

.menu-container:hover .menu,
.menu-container .menu:hover {
  display: block
}

.menu-container .menu li {
  border: 1px solid #999;
  text-align: right
}
```

```html
<div class="menu-container">
  Go to...
  <ul class="menu">
    <li>
      <a href="#">Item #1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Item #2</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Item #3</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

It will be right aligned close to the right edge of the page. I want to align the list items to the right of the list title *"Go to..."*, like the image below:

[image]

It should grow with the list item's text length to the left. This will avoid the horizontal scroll, but I can't figure out how I achieve it. Note that the menu html structure can be change if needed with no problems.

Any help will be appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give `right` property to `.menu` element.

Like:

```
.menu {
  right: 8px;
}
```

```css
.menu-container {
  width: 60px;
  float: right;
  border: 1px solid #999
}

.menu-container .menu {
  display: none;
  list-style: none;
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 80px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  right: 8px;
}

.menu-container:hover .menu,
.menu-container .menu:hover {
  display: block
}

.menu-container .menu li {
  border: 1px solid #999;
  text-align: right
}
```

```html
<div class="menu-container">
  Go to...
  <ul class="menu">
    <li>
      <a href="#">Item #1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Item #2</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Item #3</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: That's was a fast one! It worked in my original code as `right:0px`. Thank you!!

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown Its my pleasure! If this works for you, please accept the answer.

Comment: It has to be noted that the parent element is still unpositioned in this solution, so putting the `.menu-container` in another place on the site will probably have surprising (and supposedly unwanted) results.

Comment: I was waiting the minimum time to accept the answer. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

First of all (if that is intended) I'd suggest you give `.menu-container { position: relative; }` so `.menu`s position relates to this. That being accomplished, simply add `.menu { right: 0; }` to make it grow to the left.

Just as a sidenote: It is widely considered bad practice (although valid) to omit the semi-colon after the last declaration in a CSS declaration block.

```css
.menu-container {
  width: 60px;
  float: right;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  position: relative;
}

.menu-container .menu {
  display: none;
  list-style: none;
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 80px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  right: 0;  
}

.menu-container:hover .menu,
.menu-container .menu:hover {
  display: block;
}

.menu-container .menu li {
  border: 1px solid #999;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu-container">
  Go to...
  <ul class="menu">
    <li>
      <a href="#">Item #1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Item #2</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Item #3</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice tips! In fact the `position:relative` doesn't works in my original code - it is slightly different from this one I've posted here. The menu is in a header, so the list should be shown below the *Go to...* title. With `position:relative`, it throws up the title, like it appears *inside*  the `li` content, not outside. I'm not sure if I'm clear. But anyway, your answer is relevant to this question.

Comment: You don't have to use `position: relative;`, `position: absolute;` works as well to make absolute positioning of child elements relate to the parent. `position: fixed;` would also create the relationship, it just cannot be `position: static;` which is actually the default and called *unpositioned*. Since your code did not contain any deviating positioning for `.menu-container` I was assuming it would be `position: static;` as per default and wanted to point out that positioning of the parent is essential for absolute positioning of children.